# upstream deleted files showing as added in git diff

Tags: git

In the PR interface on GitHub, I can see the new changes that I've made to my branch as a diff against the master branch.

I'd like to get a list of these files from the command line.

An issue arises (on the command line) when a file was deleted on the target branch I'm diffing against (e.g. `master`) but my branch isn't aware of this change.

1. Create git repo and add file `a` to `master`.
2. Create branch `add-b` from `master` and add a file `b`. Don't merge.
3. Switch back to `master` and remove `a`. Commit.
4. Switch back to branch `add-b` and run `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A master`, which shows both `a` and `b` as having been added.

Given that `git checkout master && git merge add-b` will not *re-add* the file `a` to the repo, I understand there must be some mechanism whereby git figures this out and imagine there is a way to bubble up this information.

**What command(s) must I run to only show added / modified files, and avoid ones that have been deleted on the target branch?**

---

**Edit - example for clarity**

```
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/ryan.tuck/src/git-testing/.git/
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ touch a && git add . && git commit -m 'add a'
[master (root-commit) f65661b] add a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git checkout -b add-b
Switched to a new branch 'add-b'
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ touch b
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git add . && git commit -m 'add b'
[add-b 588960f] add b
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ ls
a b
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ ls
a
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ rm a && git add . && git commit -m 'remove a'
[master 2b4d9f8] remove a
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 a
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ ls
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git checkout add-b
Switched to branch 'add-b'
• ~/src/git-testing $$$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A master
a
b
```

Comment: I guess on step 3 you created rm-a from master as well, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no magic in what you are asking there. master has no files, and add-b has both a and b.... so both files have to be *added* for the diff to make sense..... are you struggling because you think that git is somehow considering the history of a and b (files) when comparing the branches? I don't think that is the case.... not on this example, anyway. Perhaps you would like to use something more like *the diff since both branches diverged*? If that's the case, try with ...:

```
git diff master...add-b
```

That should show you only the addition of b.

Comment: this was exactly what i was looking for to get *just* `b` to show up - thanks!